# Spell check interview problem in Bash

Tags: interview-questions, bash

Thanks for taking the time to read this.
I submitted a code screening for a company I really wanted to work for and spent a decent amount of time on their programming assignment. Pretty bummed when they just said thanks but no thanks.

Could you guys take a look and see why that might be? I was hoping to at least talk to an engineer. Thank you again.

```
DICTIONARY_INPUT="/usr/share/dict/words"

declare -A DICTIONARY

while read word; do
    word=${word,,}
    DICTIONARY[$word]=1
done < $DICTIONARY_INPUT

#for j in "${!DICTIONARY[@]}"; do
#    echo "$j"
#done

while read -p"> " input_word; do
    #echo "You entered $input_word"
    input_word=${input_word,,}
    #echo "Lowercased: $input_word"

    found=false

    # If the input is a word in the dictionary, you're done!
    if [[ ${DICTIONARY[$input_word]} ]]; then
        echo "$input_word";
        found=true
    else
        # Else, use DUPLICATE as a queue and enqueue permutations of reduced
        #+words. Use ALL_DUPLICATE as a set which removes duplicate words.
        declare -a DUPLICATE=($input_word)
        declare -A ALL_DUPLICATE

        ALL_DUPLICATE=()
        ALL_DUPLICATE[$input_word]=$input_word
        while [ ${#DUPLICATE[@]} -gt 0 ]; do
            for (( i=0; i<${#DUPLICATE}-1; i++ )); do
                if [[ ${DUPLICATE:$i:1} == ${DUPLICATE:$i+1:1} ]]; then
                    twochars=${DUPLICATE:$i:2}
                    #echo $twochars
                    removed_dup=${DUPLICATE:0:$i}${DUPLICATE:$((i+1))}
                    #echo $removed_dup
                    ALL_DUPLICATE[$removed_dup]=$removed_dup
                    if [[ ${DICTIONARY[$removed_dup]} ]]; then
                        echo "$removed_dup"
                        found=true
                        break 2
                    else
                        DUPLICATE=( "${DUPLICATE[@]}" $removed_dup)
                        #echo "New size is ${#DUPLICATE[@]}"
                    fi
                fi
            done
            DUPLICATE=(${DUPLICATE[@]:1})
            #echo "Removed size is ${#DUPLICATE[@]}"
        done

        #for j in "${!ALL_DUPLICATE[@]}"; do
        #    echo "$j"
        #done

        # If we didn't find the word yet, go through the set of duplicates
        #+and stack words with changed vowels in VOWELS. 
        # Each stack in VOWELS belongs to a particular word in ALL_DUPLICATES.
        # Iterate through the length of the word since we don't need to check 
        #+earlier letters of newly created words.     
        if ! $found; then
            #echo "Found: $found"
            declare -a VOWELS
            for j in "${!ALL_DUPLICATE[@]}"; do

                VOWELS=( $j )
                num_letters=${#VOWELS}
                for (( i=0; i<$num_letters; i++ )); do
                    for k in "${VOWELS[@]}"; do
                        if [[ ${k:$i:1} == [aeiou] ]]; then


                            change_a=${k:0:$i}a${k:$((i+1))}
                            change_e=${k:0:$i}e${k:$((i+1))}                            
                            change_i=${k:0:$i}i${k:$((i+1))}
                            change_o=${k:0:$i}o${k:$((i+1))}
                            change_u=${k:0:$i}u${k:$((i+1))}

                            #echo $change_a
                            #echo $change_e
                            #echo $change_i
                            #echo $change_o
                            #echo $change_u

                            VOWELS=( "${VOWELS[@]}" $change_a )
                            VOWELS=( "${VOWELS[@]}" $change_e )
                            VOWELS=( "${VOWELS[@]}" $change_i )
                            VOWELS=( "${VOWELS[@]}" $change_o )
                            VOWELS=( "${VOWELS[@]}" $change_u )

                            if [[ ${DICTIONARY[$change_a]} ]]; then
                                echo "$change_a"
                                found=true
                                break 3
                            elif [[ ${DICTIONARY[$change_e]} ]]; then
                                echo "$change_e"
                                found=true
                                break 3
                            elif [[ ${DICTIONARY[$change_i]} ]]; then
                                echo "$change_i"
                                found=true
                                break 3
                            elif [[ ${DICTIONARY[$change_o]} ]]; then
                                echo "$change_o"
                                found=true
                                break 3
                            elif [[ ${DICTIONARY[$change_u]} ]]; then
                                echo "$change_u"
                                found=true
                                break 3
                            fi
                        fi
                    done
                done
                VOWELS=($VOWELS[@]:1})
            done 
        fi      
    fi

    if ! $found; then
        echo "NO SUGGESTION"
    fi

done
```

[https://github.com/mrlamroger/spellcheck](https://github.com/mrlamroger/spellcheck/tree/afdde006ea2a7e703303bf1bdfd1211dc7e5b9e9)

Comment: What was the specification of the task?

Comment: why bash? Did they ask for it in bash?

Comment: @GarethRees The task was this "Write a program that reads a large list of English words (e.g. from /usr/share/dict/words on a unix system) into memory, and then reads words from stdin, and prints either the best spelling suggestion, or "NO SUGGESTION" if no suggestion can be found. The program should print ">" as a prompt before reading each word, and should loop until killed." 
More info can be found in the link about.

Comment: @WinstonEwert I've been playing around with bash recently and wanted to learn more about it. In hindsight, Python would have been cleaner.

Comment: For the purpose of screening job candidates, the quality of the code was not the deciding factor. Picking the wrong tool made your solution impractical, leading to immediate disqualification. Had you proposed a Bash solution that involved piping the words to `aspell -a`, then claimed that you had achieved a superior (but incompatible) product with less code, an enlightened interviewer _might_ like your ingenuity.

Comment: @200_success That's a bummer. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Yeah... If I got code sent to me in bash my immediate response would be: WTF? That's just not the response you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd start with

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

to indicate the shell.

Next, I don't know how much bash you must use, but I think you can at least replace a serious portion of the code by using some other tools (i.e. more UNIX style).

E.g. check if a word is in the dictionary:

```
if grep "^${input_word}$" $DICTIONARY_INPUT; then
    found=true
fi
```

`^${input_word}$` will match exactly that word (use the -i flag for case insensitivity). `grep` returns 1 if the regular expression is not found in the input file, else 0, which is why this if-expression works.

Then, a bit further you seem to try to replace all vowels with all other vowels; a oneliner for this could be

```
eval echo $(echo "$input_word" | sed 's/[aeiou]/{a,e,i,o,u}/g')
```

This makes use of a very useful feature in bash: bracket expansion. 
E.g. "a{b,c}d" expands to "ab cd".
So here, we use a regular expression that replaces every vowel in a word with {a,e,i,o,u}. E.g. hello gets `sed`'d to h{a,e,i,o,u}ll{a,e,i,o,u}. Applying bracket expansion results in a lot of words, all the combinations of vowels.

The `eval` applies this bracket expansion; the echo is needed to pass the string to eval (else it would interpret it as a command).

So, in short, this can be replaced by

```
for word in $(eval echo $(echo $input_word | sed 's/[aeiou]/{a,e,i,o,u}/g')); do
    if grep "^${word}$" $DICTIONARY_INPUT; then
        found=true
        break
    fi
done
```

You also have another section of code that checks for duplicate letters (I first wrote previous section, so that's why the order differs with your code). It can also be replaced by something like

```
eval echo $(echo "$input_word" | sed 's/\([a-z]\)\1/{\1,\1\1}/g')
```

It works similarly to previous code, but now we use backreferences in `sed` to check for duplicate letters.

These results can be combined with the for loop above to get all your combinations.
Or, at least I think so :)

I think this code is better because

- it uses some specialized tools like `sed` and `grep` which is more UNIXy
- it has less number of lines, and I think more clear (after some study) to understand and modify
- I think performance should be better, as grep is quite fast at reading input and filtering (just a guess, not really tested it)

Comment: Thanks @jerous! I'll implement changes tonight and compare performance.